# Prevent control-c from sending SIGINT to all process group children

Tags: c, terminal, signals, posix

I'm trying to interface with a really crappy, completely opaque API that creates two subprocesses within a POSIX-like environment (OS X/Linux) in C. Basically, it starts an external program and provides rudimentary support for passing messages back and forth. The process tree looks something like this:

```
+ My_program
 \
  + an initiation shell script (csh -f -c external_program_startup_script)
   \
    - the external program instance
```

When I press control-c in the terminal while `My_program` is running, the controlling terminal sends SIGINT to all processes in its process group — all three above processes.  I *want* SIGINT to get to the program instance, but if it also hits the shell script then that middle process is terminated and the communication link is severed.

Within `My_program`, I can setup a signal handler to ignore SIGINTs.  But I have absolutely no control over the two child processes (the API doesn't even expose their PIDs), so existing solutions such as changing their process group or attaching handlers won't work.  Is there a way to prevent the controlling terminal from sending SIGINT to all processes in the foreground process group?

(The API in question is [MATLAB's libeng](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-engine.html), which allows an external C program to process commands within MATLAB.  But it has absolutely no functionality for sending interrupts beyond that which the OS provides.)

Comment: I have a feeling I knew the answer to this question at some point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run sub-processes in separate control group. You can achieve that by proper usage of `setpgid()` function. After `fork()` call, in the child process run `setpgid()`, then exec the program you want to be run in separate group.

Comment: I don't have *any* access to the child process.  All the forking is obscured within one API call to a closed-source library. Using `setpgid(child_id,child_id)` from the parent errors with permission denied. That's why I'm searching for an alternative solution.

Comment: @MattB If I understood you correctly, this API call spawns the initiation shell script, right? If yes, just fork(), in child use setpgid(), then call the API function. After that you need to decide if you can quit this intermediate process, or if you need to wait for childer process to finish.

Comment: @MattB. BTW, you can also use tcsetpgrp() for setting controlling terminal - I totally forgot about this one.

Comment: Hm, yes, adding my own child to the chain could be a workable solution, but it's a pain to need yet another IPC mechanism.  I'd prefer a simpler solution if one exists.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using.  Not as pretty as I would have liked, but it's what I needed.  Thanks!