# Unexpected SIGSTOP after fork with setpgrp in Net::OpenSSH

Tags: perl

I am using Net::OpenSSH 0.61 because of
"[$SIG{INT}='IGNORE' not working with Net::OpenSSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790431/sigint-ignore-not-working-with-netopenssh)"
and I am very happy with the new setpgrp functionality.

But there is an issue I don't understand:

```
#!/opt/perl5.18.2/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $SSH1=Net::OpenSSH->new("doesnotexist",    master_setpgrp => 1);
my $SSH2=Net::OpenSSH->new("localhost",       master_setpgrp => 1);

$SSH1->test("/bin/true") or print "Error on SSH1\n";
$SSH2->test("/bin/true") or print "Error on SSH2\n";
```

Host "doesnotexist" is some host that is not reachable, down or the name is not resolvable. This reproducibly throws me back to the shell with a SIGSTOP, and I don't know how to prevent that. When omitting the new flag "master_setpgrp", the problem is not longer present.

Any hints on why this might happen?
Is this a Net::OpenSSH bug that I should report?

Thanks,

Mazze

Comment: Solved on Net::OpenSSH 0.61_17.